# Merge results of two http requests (spring integration)

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm struggling to do the following:

Make two http-requests (getData and getMetadata) and then merge the results into a payload like this: {res1: getDataResult, res2: getMetadataResult} and then pass it into 'resultChannel'.

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="request" output-channel="getData">
    <int:header name="prop" value="1"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<int-http:outbound-gateway
        request-channel="getData"
        url-expression="'https://x.y.z/{param1}'"
        http-method="GET"
        reply-channel="aggregate"
        expected-response-type="java.util.HashMap"
        request-factory="restFactory">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="param1" expression="payload.param1"/>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int-http:outbound-gateway
        request-channel="getData"
        url-expression="'https://x.y.z/{param2}'"
        http-method="GET"
        reply-channel="aggregate"
        expected-response-type="java.util.HashMap"
        request-factory="restFactory">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="param2" expression="payload.param2"/>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int:aggregator
        release-strategy-expression="size() == 2"
        input-channel="aggregate"
        output-channel="resultChannel"
        correlation-strategy-expression="headers['prop']"
        expire-groups-upon-completion="true">
</int:aggregator>
<!---->

<int:channel id="resultChannel" />
```

As input I have a payload that contains param1 and param2 that have to be used for the requests.

Comment: <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="getData" /> helped

Answer (score 0):

Use an [aggregator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator).

You will need a correlation strategy (to group the two replies); the release strategy might be as simple as `release-strategy-expression="size() == 2"`.

If you set a header, say `foo` to some value in both requests, use `correlation-strategy-expression="headers['foo']"`.

The aggregator will pair up the two replies and release them as a collection; you can then use a `<transformer/>` to produce your final result.

You can re-use the same correlation value, as long as you set `expire-groups-upon-completion="true"`. Otherwise, messages with a released correlation will be discarded.

Comment: That helps, Gary. I've updated the question. And I've got a different problem there - the aggregator doesn't seem to work in this configuration.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't much help. Turn on DEBUG logging and follow the messages through the flow. If you still can't figure it out you need to show more of your configuration. Now that both gateways consume from the same channel, you will need to use a pub-sub channel so both get the message. (But I see you figured that out).